# n-dimensional polyhedron with special properties

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I'd like to know if there exists a convex face transitive n-dimensional polyhedron with all dihedral angles equal to $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.
For n = 2,3,4 an example can be a regular hexagon, a rhombic dodecahedron and a 24-cell respectively. But I still got no idea what to do for n > 4.

Any help or ideas are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In four dimensions a second such polytope exists, which is the orthoplex/16-cell/dual of the hypercube.